# VBA Range issued

Tags: excel, vba, range

```
Sub FormatRange()

Dim xName As Range

Set xName = Range("B3", Range("B2").End(xlDown))

Sheet2.Activate

xName.Font.Color = vbRed

xName.Font.Italic = True

End Sub
```

in the above code I set my initial range in Sheet1. without a referece to sheet1. Even after I activated sheet2. The formatting get applied to sheet1 range. how come this is possible? why it didn't get applied to sheet2?

Comment: Because your formatting is applied to `xName` which you have defined as being on Sheet1 (the sheet active when you run the code). You are better off explicitly referencing the sheets to avoid confusion.

Comment: If you activated sheet2 before running the code the formatting would be applied to that sheet.

Comment: but the xName doesn't, refer to any specific sheet.

Comment: This will give you your answer ;) `Debug.Print xName.Parent.Name`

Comment: But it must apply to a sheet and will refer to whichever sheet is active at the time by default.

Comment: SJR - Formatting code is after activating the sheet2. not prior to that.. so it should get applied to sheet2 right?

Comment: Read my previous comment. You define the range **before** you switch to sheet2.

Comment: Follow Siddharth's suggestion and you will see.

Comment: As you are not explicitly referencing the sheets (as pointed out by @SJR), when you set `xName`, it points to the active sheet (in your case that would be `Sheet1`). Even if you activate `Sheet2`, your `Range` is still pointing to `Sheet1`. To avoid this confusion, always qualify your sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a range and assign it to a range object then it refers to the sheet which was active at that time. That is the beauty of it. This way you do not need to use `.Select/.Activate` to work with the range object.

The thing is that you are only looking at the `Rng.Address`. To see the complete address try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1")

    Debug.Print rng.Address(, , , True)
End Sub
```

You may want to read up on [Range.Address property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address)

**PS**: As mentioned in the comment, `.Parent.Name` would have given you the clue. It shows you the "Parent" sheet of that range :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your issue? (not tested)

```
Set xName = ActiveSheet.Range("B3", ActiveSheet.Range("B2").End(xlDown))
```